# Add/Update data in specific row of CSV file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, csv

I developed a program - a data matcher of two CSV file. Sample input of the data in CSV file is below.

user_transaction:

user name       |        email       |      amount  |  blank   | total  |  n/a |  ok | bank name | date

[image]

bank_transaction:

date | transact details | n/a | location  | blank  | **for status** | amount

[image]

So what my program do is looking for all bank transaction(date and amount) match to users data.

Here is my code doing it..
[jdoodle.com/a/3Ev](http://jdoodle.com/a/3Ev)

Any idea?
When clicking **done** of a specific row should add data to the status row from the bank_transaction CSV file. 
My purpose here is to mark `done` all that I have check/confirm bank transaction detail.

Example output in CSV:[image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem when doing it? Please share an example of your attempt to do so.

Answer (score 1):

> When I click done of a specific row, How can I add data to the status row

For the form (where your button "Done") just set the row number (or file position from `ftell`; then `fseek` to focus on), it'll simplify the update.

Also do not use customized parsers for CSV. Try `fgetcsv`

```
// Open file, cursor at the beginning
$stream = fopen('bank_transaction.csv', 'r+', false);
// Take focus position
$idx = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ftell', 0, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if ($idx) {
    fseek($stream, $idx);
    // $maxLineLength - define it earlier
    $data = fgetcsv($stream, $maxLineLength, ',', '"');
    ... update required field ...
    // Set position back after read
    fseek($stream, $idx);
    fputcsv($stream, $data, ',', '"');
}
```

Comment: I got your point. From my code how can I get the specific row and position of of the item to add?

Comment: `<a href="">Done</a>` change to `<form merthod="POST"><input type="submit" value="Done" /><input type="hidden" name="ftell" value="<?= $transaction['ftell'] ?>" />` and put `ftell`-function before `fgetscv` (`for` - is not the right place... but it can be `for(; $ftell = ftell($csv_payment_array), $depositlist = fgetcsv($csv_payment_array );) { ...` ).

Comment: Can you please look at my updated code? Seems not working (it just load the whole page). Or did I missed something here? https://www.jdoodle.com/a/3Ev

Comment: I see the error on the hidden input, it does not have value `<input type="hidden" name="ftell" value="<?=$transaction['ftell'] ?>` says `Undefined index: ftell`

Comment: Yep, you have to define it by your own by using $ftell variable from the comment above

Comment: Is `<?=$transaction['ftell'] ?>` should equal to the row number of the data to update? If yes? How can I get the row number of the specific data?

Comment: `$ftell = ftell($csv)` - could tell you about the current (and required for you) position in the file